# Arquillian test under security manager throws NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, junit4, jboss-arquillian, wildfly-10

I have a WildFly 10.1 environment where I am starting the container using the following config:

```
<container qualifier="container.active-1" mode="suite" default="true">
    <configuration>
        <property name="jbossHome">${wildFlyInstallDir}</property>
        <property name="jbossArguments">-secmgr</property>
        <property name="javaVmArguments">
            -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
            -Djgroups.bind_addr=127.0.0.1
            -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=137
            -Djava.security.policy=./arquillian.policy
        </property>
    </configuration>
</container>
```

When I do not specify the `-secmgr` argument, the instance starts and the test is executed just fine; however when I use the security management argument to trigger using the security manager, I get the following exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:713)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:734)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.spi.util.TestRunners.getTestRunner(TestRunners.java:60)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.spi.util.TestRunners.getTestRunner(TestRunners.java:44)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:169)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1$1.run(ServletInitialHandler.java:110)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:107)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I need to execute my Arquillian test case using the security manager and I'm not clear what I could have missed as a part of my configuration.

The pertinent gradle libraries are:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:1.1.12.Final
org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:1.1.12.Final
org.wildfly.arquillian:wildfly-arquillian-container-managed:2.0.0.Final
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the ShrinkWrap deployment was not including a `permissions.xml` file and thus the exception was being thrown.   Once I added that file, things worked.